# C2DM do not receive any of sent messages

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I have one question about C2DM, I registered yesterday and I got email that my mail and app are approved. From app I get registration_id, I have broadcast_receiver like

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();

    android.util.Log.d("REG_1","onReceive");


    if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION".equals(action)) {
        final String registrationId = intent
                .getStringExtra("registration_id");
        String error = intent.getStringExtra("error");

        android.util.Log.d("REG_1",registrationId);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String token = prefs.getString("token", null);
        String userId;
        try {
            userId = RestClient.getUserIdByToken(token).getString(
                    "user_id");

            Intent i = new Intent(context, RegService.class);
            i.putExtra("c2dm_registration_id",registrationId);
            i.putExtra("token", token);
            i.putExtra("user_id", userId);
            i.putExtra("device_id", "bla");
            i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            context.startService(i);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        saveRegistrationId(context, registrationId);
    }
```

and I enter in this function during registration and I send messages from command line like

```
curl https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin -d Email=MYGOOGLEACCOUNT@gmail.com -d "Passwd=MY_PASSWORD" -d accountType=GOOGLE -d source=Google-cURL-Example -d service=ac2dm
```

and

```
curl --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=DQAAAMMAAAC58D4X-5zjQFdYuGz7D9DhnuN4OUiz_gCtOJRSNwNLN0-wxveAEVL985hNKJXyQ_7U4sTfsUGh_3OXMLKpB5PNN1eaI4AfT19LaJ1vGJCZ_sSE0NDqGsC0mZVdMsYbE2Sz1r1WE_p5WNokfGMRdmxIHl0QCWb43lTD3iCvr51ujmnHnvpn2mDLWr6j9DtyDxADRw1to2iGgpJNelXmIA8tOzjyqF3szN-N2IYnihJ8H2t3G5wotOWy1EahB43Lv2NPdlV-A4yVSbdsYGM_AVdd" "https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send" -d registration_id=APA91bHhbsPedDVnYCaSJQMhWjfjK3W9jOaMgVITUHqw97w4fF_8fermSG22CzFvpPuTyRKnJFyJ_iwfgJEJ4uidURxuHZCCBuPtGAsv6NeVipmOd53Fkru_A3NW3cpIMo9gvuVxIB0QqxOvl1SmVfqRzD4qQfSNaw -d "data.test_result=This data will be send to your application as payload" -d collapse_key=2
id=0:1322216144957968%b3c4048a00000032
```

but it never enter in onHandle function of broadcatreceiver.

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.surveyce.android.c2dm.C2DMRegistrationReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.surveyce.android" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- Receive the registration id -->
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.surveyce.android" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

...

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />-->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.surveyce.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.surveyce.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Did anybody have similar strange problems  that get registrationId and send messages but do not receive message on phone ? What can be problem, maybe because I registered yesterday ( but how than I get rigistrationId and auth for that account) ? Package names and gmail are account are 100% ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a service tag [write your receiver name in below service tag which is sub class of C2DMBaseReceiver]

```
<service android:name=".C2DMReceiver" />
```

Use C2DMBroadcastReceiver Instead of C2DMRegistrationReceiver

```
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
```

Comment: C2DMRegistrationReceiver is custom class and  extends BroadcastReceiver. What is C2DMBroadcastReceiver ? DO I need some .jar to include, where to find example with this ? Where to find C2DMBaseReceiver ? Thanks!

Comment: C2DMBroadcastReceiver is also child class of BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: And you don't need add any external .jar to include, just add three opensource classes in your project. you can find that classes here.   http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/source/browse/trunk/android/c2dm/com/google/android/c2dm/?r=2

Comment: I could found best example here  http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You can refer following Link for proper implementation of C2DM [Google C2DM service](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/)